# MySQL using WHERE clause with multiple LIKEs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple table with names, some beginning with a letter and some beginning with a number. I am trying to filter out the names that start with a number, and only select the names that start with a letter of the alphabet.

Here are a few of my attempts, which have failed to produce the desired results:

```
SELECT name 
  from subjects 
 WHERE name LIKE ('A%') AND 
 WHERE name LIKE ('B%') AND 
 WHERE name LIKE ('C%')...;

SELECT name 
  from subjects 
 WHERE name LIKE ('A%', 'B%', 'C%', ...);

SELECT name 
  from subjects 
 WHERE name LIKE ('A%') AND ('B%') AND ('C%') ...;
```

Thank you, in advance, for your help. I appreciate it very much. Stack Overflow has been my savior so many times as I am learning to program with PHP and MySQL.
Lori

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would be use [regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator instead of passing multiple `like`s.

Try:

```
SELECT name from subjects WHERE name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]';
```

This will select all records with name starting with both lowercase and uppercase alphabets.

Comment: Thank you! I thought there was a way to use regular expressions, but that is a new world to me.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are having is you have included multiple wheres.  Simply remove them

```
SELECT name 
  from subjects 
 WHERE name LIKE ('A%') AND 
 name LIKE ('B%') AND 
 name LIKE ('C%')...;
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. My syntax was just a bit off, I see. I see now how to make that work, but REGEX appears to be my best bet.

Comment: They should be ORs, not ANDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regexp:

```
SELECT name 
FROM subjects 
WHERE name
REGEXP '[A-Za-z]'
```